# Adding a class to Yii2 CRUD GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I've been trying to add a class to the images' column in the CRUD GridView in Yii2. So far, I've managed to display the image, but at its full width and height. I need to add a 'col-md-3' bs class to the image.

This is what I pulled off:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'emp_firstname',
        'emp_lastname',
        'emp_photo' => [
            'format' => 'image',
            'attribute' => 'emp_photo',
            'value' => 'emp_photo',
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'col-md-3'],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form the column group you can use options http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$options-detail

```
'emp_photo' => [
        'format' => 'image',
        'attribute' => 'emp_photo',
        'value' => 'emp_photo',
        'options' => ['class' => 'col-md-3'],
    ],
```

but you should complete the "bootstrap grid" in the other columns

Comment: I've added ['image', ['class' => 'col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2']] to the 'format' in the 'emp_photo' array, and it works properly.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to add id or class or both to the table 
try this.

```
'tableOptions' => [
        'id' => 'theDatatable',
        'class'=>'table table-striped table-bordered'
        ],
```